# Tag synonym request: duplicate -> [duplicate-files]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/duplicate)'s wiki says:

> Two or more files that exactly same.

... which is pretty much what [duplicate-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files) says right in the name. Either way would do, but one of them must go.

---

Aside: Ah. We can't have `[duplicate]` in question titles. :D